# Unmarshalling generic child using Jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an xml file in the format:-

```
<item>
    <item_attribute index="1" type="1" >
        <name>value1</name>
    </item_attribute>
    <item_attribute index="2" type="1" >
        <a_differnt_name>value2</a_different_name>
    </item_attribute>
    <item_attribute index="5" type="2" >
        <another_name>value3</another_name>
    </item_attribute>
</item>
```

I am using JAXB to unmarshall the xml and have a class set up for each element other than the child of the 'item_attribute'. I want to generically unmarshall the data (element name and element value) within each 'item_attribute' element without knowing what the element is called.

All I know is the 'item_attribute' always has  only 1 child element and that child could be called and contain anything.

I tried using:

```
public class Item_attribute {

    private int index;
    private Object data;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "index")
    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }
    public void setIndex(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    public Object getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

}
```

but it keeps throwing an illegalannotationexception!

Comment: I think you should use `Integer` instead of `int`

Answer (score 0):

If you annotate the field (instance variable) you need to add the following type level annotation:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo {

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    private Object data;

     public Object getData() {  
          return this.data;
     }

}
```

Or you can put the annotation on the get method.

```
public class Foo {

    private Object data;

     @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
     public Object getData() {  
          return this.data;
     }

}
```

Comment: Hi I tried this and it didnt work - it still throws the same error

Comment: @user1155083 - Could you post the stack trace?

Comment: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement does not have a no-arg default constructor.

Comment: @user1155083 - Could you post the code where you create the `JAXBContext`?

Answer (score 0):

Add @XmlAnyElement(lax=true) to every error(javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement does not have a default constructor)

Comment: A little more explanation might help out the fellow programmers to understand how the it works.